# $wpdb is not initiating

Tags: database

I am new to the wordpress and want to create a plugin but `$wpdb` is not initiating, I am using wordpress version 4.9.4

Here is my code snippet

```
global $wpdp;
$sql    = 'SELECT * From '.$wpdp->prefix.' my_first_plugin';
$result = $wpdp->get_results($sql);
```

Comment: Where is this code? (in which hook/filter) Did you check for errors? (your SQL query is invalid)

Answer (score 3):

You have written $wpdb incorrectly (3x) in your code example. If it is an exact copy it will never work. And you have a space in your SQL after prefix.' which shouldn't be there. And 'From' shoul dbe all caps.

Try this:

```
global $wpdb;
$sql    = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'my_first_plugin';
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```